# SQL query - rubocop line too long

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, rubocop

I've got a SQL query inside my ruby code but my rubocop is giving me an error in WHEN line - `layout/linelength line is too long. [128/120]`. What is the proper way to divide query below?

```
  SELECT
    bank_transfers.date AS day,
    CAST(SUM(bank_transfers.amount_cents) AS BIGINT) AS gross_value,
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN bank_transfers.amount_cents < 0 THEN bank_transfers.amount_cents END) AS BIGINT) AS expenses_sum,
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN bank_transfers.amount_cents > 0 THEN bank_transfers.amount_cents END) AS BIGINT) AS revenues_sum
  FROM bank_transfers
  JOIN customers ON customers.id = bank_transfers.customer_id
  WHERE customers.id = #{customer.id}
  AND bank_transfers.date < '#{Date.current}'
  AND bank_transfers.date >= '#{final_past_date}'
  GROUP BY day
```

Comment: I would argue that Rubocop doesn't report errors. It just gives suggestions to follow a certain style guide or to discuss with your co-workers how code should look like. Therefore I think it is perfectly fine to ignore (disable) certain offenses when you think the code looks fine and is easy to read and to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Your current formatting is what a SQL beautifier would suggest. So your solutions are mostly workaround. Here are 3 approaches. I would recommend you to pick the one your prefer (I tend to prefer the first one).

1. If there is a mismatch with robocop I you can deactivate robocop line length just for this block:

```rb
# rubocop:disable Metrics/LineLength 
...
 SELECT
    bank_transfers.date AS day,
    CAST(SUM(bank_transfers.amount_cents) AS BIGINT) AS gross_value,
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN bank_transfers.amount_cents < 0 THEN bank_transfers.amount_cents END) AS BIGINT) AS expenses_sum,
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN bank_transfers.amount_cents > 0 THEN bank_transfers.amount_cents END) AS BIGINT) AS revenues_sum
  FROM bank_transfers
  JOIN customers ON customers.id = bank_transfers.customer_id
  WHERE customers.id = #{customer.id}
  AND bank_transfers.date < '#{Date.current}'
  AND bank_transfers.date >= '#{final_past_date}'
  GROUP BY day
...
# rubocop:enable Metrics/LineLength
```

2. Play with the SQL query to be something else like removing tab or having more line break. (just putting one of the option below). Big downside: lower readability.

```
SELECT
bank_transfers.date AS day,
CAST(SUM(bank_transfers.amount_cents) AS BIGINT) AS gross_value,
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN bank_transfers.amount_cents < 0 THEN bank_transfers.amount_cents END) AS BIGINT) AS expenses_sum,
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN bank_transfers.amount_cents > 0 THEN bank_transfers.amount_cents END) AS BIGINT) AS revenues_sum
FROM bank_transfers
JOIN customers ON customers.id = bank_transfers.customer_id
WHERE customers.id = #{customer.id}
AND bank_transfers.date < '#{Date.current}'
AND bank_transfers.date >= '#{final_past_date}'
GROUP BY day
```

3. Or construct your query with string insertion

```rb
subqueryA = 'CASE WHEN bank_transfers.amount_cents < 0 THEN bank_transfers.amount_cents END) AS BIGINT'
subqueryB = 'CASE WHEN bank_transfers.amount_cents > 0 THEN bank_transfers.amount_cents END) AS BIGINT'
...
SELECT
    bank_transfers.date AS day,
    CAST(SUM(bank_transfers.amount_cents) AS BIGINT) AS gross_value,
    CAST(#{subqueryA}) AS expenses_sum,
    CAST(#{subqueryB}) AS revenues_sum
FROM bank_transfers
JOIN customers ON customers.id = bank_transfers.customer_id
WHERE customers.id = #{customer.id}
AND bank_transfers.date < '#{Date.current}'
AND bank_transfers.date >= '#{final_past_date}'
GROUP BY day
```